# Error while deploying contract to the Ropsten testnet

Tags: contract-deployment, ropsten, truffle-migration

I'm trying to deploy a contract (called "FilesDetailsManager") to the Ropsten Testnet using Truffle and Infura as provider.
But when I type into terminal `truffle migrate --network ropsten`, I get this error:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"FileDetailsManager" -- only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC.
```

I searched online but I did not get any advice for solving the issue, and I actually don't know what this error means.

Do you have any idea about how to solve the problem or what the error means?
Thank you in advance for the time spent reading.

PS: The `truffle-config.js` file looks like this (if it can be useful):

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const path = require("path");
const MNEMONIC = 'wallet key censored';

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    develop: {
      port: 8545
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC , "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/infura api key censored")
      },
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the upcoming Berlin fork. Ropsten has performed the upgrade, however the associated tooling (Truffle + Infura) has not handled the change smoothly. You can see more information in a conversation [here](https://twitter.com/peter_szilagyi/status/1369658120193052675) between Péter Szilágyi (Geth), E.G. Galano (Infura), and Tim Coulter (Truffle). This issue should be resolved shortly.

In the mean time, you have two options:

1. Use a network other than Ropsten.
2. Use your own, upgraded node instead of nfura

Comment: Thank you for the clear and coincise answer!

Comment: The [Infura status page](https://status.infura.io/incidents/gryqdx4fnhm1) implies that this issue has been resolved.